# Tangent points of a circle touching two functions

Tags: calculus

I'm really confused with this and don't quite know where to start, and was hoping that I could get a booster in the right direction!

See the picture, but here's a written description: A graph has two graphs plotted on it, $x=\ln(x)$ and $x=\ln(-x)$, to make a funnel shape. A circle is resting inside of that funnel, with a radius of $2$. How can I find a) the center point of the circle (which rests on the $y$-axis, I just need to know the $y$- value), and b) the tangent points or points of contact between the circle and the two plotted functions.

If you're looking at the graph, then it would be points $P$ and $Q$ for the tangent points and point $R$ for the center of the circle.

[image]

Thank you!

BTW: please don't just give the answer! I just need a pointer on what to find and where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

**Start from the end and go back**. 
Note that the segment $RQ$ is orthogonal to the tangent line to the graph of $\ln(x)$ at the point $Q$. So given a generic $x_0>0$, this the "action plan":

1) Find the equation of tangent line at $Q=(x_0,\ln(x_0))$.

2) Find the line orthogonal at $Q$ to the tangent line.

3) Determine the intersection point $R$ of the orthogonal line and the line $x=0$.

4) Now that we have the $y$-value of $R$ as a function of $x_0$, find $x_0>0$ such that the the distance between $R$ and $Q$ is $2$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is there a way to find the generic x-value algebraically, rather than graphically?

Comment: Yes! My hint is a "list of things to do" in order to find the result.  "find the tangent line at $Q$" means write down the equation of this tangent line. What is the equation?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**
I think the equations should be

$$y=ln(x)........(1)$$
$$y=ln(-x)........(2)$$
$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=4........(3)$$
Now at tangent point the slope of the circle and the given graph will be the same.so,
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\bigg((x-h)^2+(y-k)^2-4\bigg)=\dfrac{d}{dx}\bigg(ln(\pm x)\bigg)........(4)$$

You will get a system of equations here..4 equations,4 unknown...
Just solve them.

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

Draw normal/tangent at $Q$ cutting symmetry line at $R$

Coordinates $$ Q:\quad (x_1, \log \,x_1) $$

Slope is the derivative evaluated at that point.

$$ \tan \phi= 1/x =1/x_1 $$

Difference along central symmetry axis, vertical component of $QR$

$$ h = x_1 \cot \phi $$

Coordinates $$ R: (0,\, \log x_1 +h) $$

Equation of circle tangent at $ (P,Q) $ centered at $R:$

$$ (x- 0)^2 + [y-(\log\, x_1 +h)]^2 = (h/\sin \phi)^2 $$